# C++ primer plus list:10.9 The “top” pointer problem

Tags: c++

**strong text**

The list show the `top = &top->topval(stocks[st])`, this means that 'top' point to its own address then point to `topval()`'s return object? I can't understand.

Comment: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57990421/edit) the question to add a [mcve]. Even with the image the question is unclear. Dont post code as images  please

Comment: @Mr.Weson If you had posted code instead of an image of code, you could fix it instead of commenting on how it is wrong. Also, comments are ephemeral, so any corrections should be made in the question itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand in front of `&top->topval(...)` returns the address of the object returned from `topval`. This is because the member access operator `->` has higher precedence than the address-of operator. So when we assume that `Stock::topval` returns a reference to another `Stock` object, we can get the address of that one and bind it to `Stock *top`.